# JQuery datepicker dropdown after selection shows -1 month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am running into an issue with the JQuery datepicker.  When I try and use the month selector I get a selection that is the one month prior to the month I selected.  You can see what I mean here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh4Cz/)

Here is the code I am using:

```
<input id="StartDate" />


$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "0",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showCurrentAtPos: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your JsFiddle example you are trying to set a datepicker with one month visible. In that case setting both `numberOfMonths` and `showCurrentAtPos` its pointless.

You should be alright deleting that.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths

As you can see, "`showCurrentAtPos`" is only used if you are showing multiple month instances.

Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sh4Cz/1/

Comment: If you add in the showCurrentAtPos: 1 and numberOfMonths: 3   The result will be that you have the starting month in the center month (current month) and then when you use the dropdown for month it will no longer work correctly.  It seems like the showCurrentAtPos has a bug to it.

Comment: Guess that problem has been here for a while.    http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6225

Answer (score 0):

showCurrentAtPos: 1

When I took this out it seemed to work just fine.